# Is there a plugin for always spawning with the same items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I need a plugin that lets me set an item/items that players always spawn with. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wrote a quick plugin that will do this for you. It's called StartingItems, and you can find it on BukkitDev [here](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/starting-items/). It supports both respawn items and items for players that first login. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running [Bukkit Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/essentials/) on the server, there is a /kit command. You can set up "/kit starter" such that players can use this command immediately upon entering the game to get started. It should be noted that, unless you tie to an economy mod or some other way of tracking it, they can use this command over and over. You may not want that. It's not a perfect solution, but it might achieve your goals, so I thought I would recommend it.